# How to show a section list in `DropdownSearch` widget?

Tags: flutter, dropdown

Here I have implemented this `dropdownSearch` widget and showing a simple list which is working fine, but now I want to show a section list instead of a simple list:

here my code showing a simple list:

```
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class MyDropdownSearchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDropdownSearchWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyDropdownSearchWidget> createState() => _MyDropdownSearchWidgetState();
}

class _MyDropdownSearchWidgetState extends State<MyDropdownSearchWidget> {
  // Define your data source for the dropdown items.
  final List<String> items = [
    'Item 1',
    'Item 2',
    'Item 3',
    'Item 4',
    'Item 5',
    'Item 6',
    'Item 7',
    'Item 8',
    'Item 9',
    'Item 10',
    'Item 11',
    'Item 12',
    'Item 13',
    'Item 14',
    'Item 15',
    'Item 16'
  ];

  String? selectedValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Dropdown Search Example"),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DropdownSearch<String>(
              popupProps: const PopupProps.bottomSheet(
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                searchDelay: Duration(milliseconds: 10),
                showSelectedItems: true,
                showSearchBox: true,
                searchFieldProps: TextFieldProps(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Search project... ex: Feeta",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                )),
                bottomSheetProps: BottomSheetProps(
                    elevation: 1,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: .5))),
                title: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        "All projects",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: Colors.black87),
                      ),
                    )),
              ),
              dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
                  dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.layers_rounded),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: "Select a project",
              )),
              items: items,
              onChanged: (String? value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = value; // Update the selected value
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              "Selected Item: ${selectedValue ?? 'None'}",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

package version:

`dropdown_search: ^5.0.6`

can anyone please tell me how I can show a section list in this `dropdownSearch` widget?

Answer (score 0):

Going through the [examples](https://github.com/salim-lachdhaf/searchable_dropdown/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) I've found out this library has multi level support. Maybe you can use it.

You can add `items` like this

```dart
  final List<MultiLevelString> myItems = [
    MultiLevelString(level1: "1"),
    MultiLevelString(level1: "2"),
    MultiLevelString(
      level1: "3",
      subLevel: [
        MultiLevelString(level1: "sub3-1"),
        MultiLevelString(level1: "sub3-2"),
      ],
    ),
    MultiLevelString(level1: "4")
  ];
```